# Simplest CMS ever?

Tags: content-management-system, gatsby

I’m building a super simple website with 5 pages and I want a CMS that allows me to change the text and the pictures in a couple of them.

In the past I used wordpress, but it has way too many features that i don’t need in this case.

I’ve been trying to learn gatsby.js so I would like to build it on that, but trying to see how to source from Netlify-CMS I started facing an overwhelming amount of information which I'm not sure I need.

Any tips?

Thanks!

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used Forestry.io, a good simple solution that did exactly what I needed in combination with Jekyll.

Answer (score 0):

Netlify has a built in CMS, and it's compatible with Gatsby! You can find examples online.  It should be good for smaller sites, but for larger projects, I really like Prismic.io.  Contentful is another popular one, but it's a bit pricier than prismic.

Edit: reread your comment about sourcing from Netlify.  Netlify is not a "source" plug in in Gatsby.  You use a local file +markdown source, and do the configuration for netlify, which adds an admin interface at an endpoint. You configure your data models in the interface, create login, etc.  Then, when you submit changes, it modifies files in your connected git repo, so the local file + remark will make the data available in the graphql queries.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!

I actually meant "I'm sourcing from Netlify-CMS", good to get confirmation that that's a good idea. 

I'm still fighting with it since all of it (gatsby.js, react, graphql etc.) is very new to me, but it seems achievable :)